# EOF while attempting go-pgp

Tags: go, pgp, openpgp

I need to pgp encrypt a string in Go and I read that this library was good: "github.com/jchavannes/go-pgp/pgp"

**main.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    encrypted := encrypt("4007400000000007", "123")
    fmt.Println(encrypted)
}
```

**encrypt.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jchavannes/go-pgp/pgp"
)

func encrypt(ccNum string, cvv string) string {
    sourceString := `{"cardNumber":"` + ccNum + `","cvv":"` + cvv + `"}`
    fmt.Println(sourceString)
    pubEntity, err := pgp.GetEntity([]byte(TestPublicKey), []byte{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    encrypted, err := pgp.Encrypt(pubEntity, []byte(sourceString))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    return string(encrypted)
}

const TestPrivateKey = `-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----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=5NT7
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----`

const TestPublicKey = `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----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=gO1a
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`
```

When I run the code I get:

```
{"cardNumber":"4007400000000007","cvv":"123"}
panic: EOF

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.encrypt({0x561363?, 0x60?}, {0x55f3af?, 0x0?})
        /home/peter/Documents/go-projects/circle-pgp-driver/encrypt.go:14 +0x196
main.main()
        /home/peter/Documents/go-projects/circle-pgp-driver/main.go:6 +0x31
```

Any idea what causes this panic?

Answer (score 1):

Had faced similar issue, was solved by putting a new line after `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----` in the key string, looks similar for your case.

like

```
const TestPublicKey = `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

xsFNBFkNK+ABEADUpjJ/kz3j+iz9qnzUb6ONw+WHSLp8umnd1z06SBVkWFjYReqf
....
```